# Edge detection using wavelet

Tags: windows

I had done Edge detection using wavelet transform using thus steps
      changing the image to Gray scale 
       decomposing the image using dwt2(discrete wavelet transform,Haar wavelet filter  ) in to horizontal,vertical,diagonal and approximation(detail)
       further decomposing the horizontal part 
       threshold (global threshold like canny Edge detection )
 i got the edge but i got a problem while locating the edge to complete image to mean recovering original image using only the Edges  so i need help concerning this either in concept ,mat lab code or references 
           I hope i will get your help soon

Answer (score 0):

Before your transformation to gray scale you could try filtering the image of specific color ranges which may simplify the problem.  This is a tactic used to weaken Captchas before sending it off to an OCR like [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)

Another tool that may help is a [Flood Fill Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).